# SQL data format

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Why is this not working? any idea? I have changed the decimal places as well.

```
SELECT 
    cust_id,
    cast(score as decimal(16,4)) as score
FROM 
    xyz 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-02'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

> ERROR: bad character in format or data of XYZ table

```
score is VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
```

I have used it as a varchar and ofcourse it works but I want to change the field in decimal because I want to make buckets

Comment: Check that all your data is able to be casted to decimal

Comment: Use TRYCAST instead of CAST. If the value can't be cast to the target type, it returns NULL instead. You can even look for rows where the "score" is not NULL but the TRYCAST value is null, if you want to find offending rows and see if there is something else that could be done with them.

Comment: @JaimeDrq worked thanks!

Comment: @Fred thankyou! Will try that!